# Inserting default value for null dates in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with null-able dates. This has a default constraint of getdate(). If a date is not supplied today's date is inserted.  However, I want to convert null's to todays date as well.

Is there a way to force the date to today's date when a null is supplied on an insert.

*I do  not want to change this to a non-nullable field.*

Comment: You'll need to write an `AFTER INSERT` trigger in that case

Comment: have you tried something like `ISNULL(DATE, getdate())`

Comment: Your second two paragraphs contradict each other.

Comment: Not sure where the contradiction is so let me clarify - I don't want to change the column to non-nullable but I want to force all inserts with a null date to insert today's date instead.

Comment: The comment by Marc_s led me to the solution...many thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
  Update table
    set Date =Getdate()
    where date=null
```